# Why will this not trigger on a pull request push commit update?

Tags: github-actions

```
name: blabla bacon n eggs
on:
    pull_request:
        branches:
            - basickarl/gh-actions-pr

defaults:
    run:
        shell: bash

jobs:
    somting:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - run: echo "testy"
```

I have pushed my code on the branch stated to the origin repo in github. I have created a pull request. I updated some code on the branch and pushed, but the actions is not triggering? How does one trigger a github action workflow when updating a pull request?

The updates to the branch I am making is the workflow file itself.

Here is an example repo: https://github.com/basickarl/github-actions/actions/workflows/test.yaml

For some reason only `on: [pull_request]` seems to work.

Comment: If you inform the branch, the `pull_request` event needs to be from any branch to this specific branch (in your case, the workflow will trigger only for PR opened to the `basickarl/gh-actions-pr` branch). If you want the workflow to trigger every time you edit the PR, you can add the type `edited` as well as the branch name. More information can be found on the documentation here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request

Comment: Moreover, if you want the workflow to trigger for each push commit to your specific branch, you need to add the push event to the workflow `on` condition as well, the same way you did for the pull request.

Answer (score 1):

Use types: [synchronize] under on: pull-request:

Comment: You can format the code by using `a code block here`. You can also explain why it cna resolve the author issue